# iOS: How can a custom camera save images always in the right orientation?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm currently implementing a custom camera with IOS. I want the camera to save images to album always in the correct direction just like the official iOS camera: no matter in what orientation you hold the camera you can always see the photo save the correct orientation.
I checked many source code, they seem to save the image rather arbitrarily with the following:

```
var image  = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
```

But this only works when the device is upright
Could anyone provide any suggestions?

I also tried to get the orientation

```
let uiorientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
```

But it always returns portrait when the screen is portrait locked.

Answer (score 3):

You have to update the image rotation when you get `UIImage` object. 
Pass the image that is getting from image picker to this method

### Swift

```
func getNormalizedImage(rawImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    if (rawImage.imageOrientation == .up) {
        return rawImage
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rawImage.size, false, rawImage.scale)
    rawImage.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:rawImage.size.width, height:rawImage.size.height))

    let normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return normalizedImage!
}
```

### Objective-C

```
+(UIImage *)getNormalizedImage:(UIImage *)rawImage {

    if(rawImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp)
    return rawImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rawImage.size, NO, rawImage.scale);
    [rawImage drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, rawImage.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return normalizedImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I wanted. I get CGImage from capture method in a AVCapture delegate. In which there is no valid orientation information(The orientation is always up). I need to assign orientation by detecting the orientation of the device/interface

Comment: you can convert cgimage to UIimage and set a default orientation = .up